# Breaking a wood block in Adventure mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I break a wood block in Adventure mode?

Comment: In future, please clarify your questions with what the problem is and what you have tried. Remember, the idea of these questions is so that others in the future can find answers to the problems too.

Comment: In adventure mode you are not supposed to break any block without having the proper tools that come with a special NBT tag containing the individual blocks you can break with them.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft that doesn't work in adventure mode, You are thinking about survival mode.

Comment: @sibbles100 Adventure mode does not give you permanent Mining Fatigue 3.

Answer (score 9):

To break wood (logs) in adventure mode, you need a tool which is specially enabled to destroy logs by having it's `CanDestroy` tag set to include `"minecraft:log"` for oak, birch, spruce and jungle logs, and/or `"minecraft:log2"` for old oak or acacia logs. There is no way to limit it to specific data values, so you can't make an axe that is capable of chopping oak but not birch or something like that. The tag takes a list (`[]`) of item ids.

For example

```
/give @p minecraft:iron_axe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:log","minecraft:log2"]}
```

gives you an iron axe capable of chopping all kinds of logs, which will be indicated in it's tooltip as well. It does not chop planks or any other wooden things.

NB: The mining speed is then determined by the tool itself, so while you can make log-chopping sticks, the speed would be the same as hitting a tree with a stick in survival.

Answer (score 2):

You can only break blocks with proper tools, I.e. Dirt requires a shovel. Really, unless you enabled bonus chest, you can't do anything. If it is a server, ask for an axe or someone to break it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break blocks in adventure mode unless the map creator gives you a tool that he used code to get

Answer (score 0):

In Adventure Mode, you can't break wood unless you have an axe, and since you just started you have no axe. However I found a way to start your gameplay in Adventure Mode as ETHANWEEGEE mentioned. First you must create a world and click on bonus chest so when you start the world there is a chest with some materials. There's a chance there is going to be an axe in the bonus chest. Take the other items, mine the chests with the axe, and start mining the wood and get started crafting. You might want to make a shovel if you're going to collect stone from underneath since theres dirt and grass above. You can also use cheats too.