# Making unbreakable blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having a dilemma, I am trying to make a Prison Game in vanilla Minecraft, but can't make a part work.

I give the players this command to stop them from breaking blocks `/gamemode a @a[r=40]`  When they enter onto the logs they are switched to survival `/gamemode s @a[r=17]`

This is my problem:  *From the logs, where they are in survival mode they can still reach the wood planks and destroy them up until the lime green wool*

[image]

I hoped the gamemode switch would solve this, but unfortunately it didn't quite do it.  So I was thinking there may be a way to stop this and I need them to be unbreakable or something like it.

Comment: Have you tried using bedrock? It looks ugly but is unbreakable unless you are in creative. Also, if you only want them to be able to break certain types of blocks, you could keep them in adventure and supply them with a tool which has the relevant `canDestory` tags or whatever

Comment: Yeah it looks ugly that's why I didn't use it, but your can destroy tag sounds interesting.  So give an axe a tag that only allows it to break logs?

Comment: [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225717/breaking-a-wood-block-in-adventure-mode/225726#225726) and [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246298/104515) would be helpful. Also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pT46pW3uL4).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36629/discussion-between-jason-and-angussidney).